# rewiev: При парсинге с помощью awk изменить последнюю строчку

Tags: bash, инспекция-кода, sed, awk

Есть скрипт, который парсит txt файл с разным количеством строк вида:

```
project1 220EEOOBC45
project2 BC45220EEO3
project...
projectn 3563GFGFG34
```

и дописывает в json:

```
{ "name": "project1", "revision": "220EEOOBC45"},
{ "name": "project2", "revision": "BC45220EEO3"},
....
{ "name": "projectn", "revision": "3563GFGFG34"}]}
```

скрипт:

```
 awk '{print "{ \"name\": \"" $1 "\", \"revision\": \"" substr($2,1,12) "\"},"}END{print "{ \"name\": \"" $1 "\", \"revision\": \"" substr($2,1,12) "\"}]}"}' info.txt >> result.json
 sed -i -n 'x;1b;$x;p' result.json
```

Соответственно, начало json файла уже есть и стоит задача лишь дописать.
Я использую awk, который после обработки последней строчки дублирует ее, но с закрывающими тегами *]}* и без запятой, а sed затем удаляет предпоследнюю задублированную строчку. Мне кажется это каким-то очень странным велосипедом.
Какие могут быть еще варианты или более адекватные рабочие решения?
К сожалению, *jq* или подобное использовать невозможно. Что-то из разряда плюс-минус awk, sed, coreutils.

Comment: А питон тоже нельзя?

Comment: @mkkik сложный вопрос на самом деле. Скорее нет, чем да. С одной стороны это используется и на win машинах. И хочется обойтись стандартным и минимальным набором инструментов. Даже perl не особо хотелось бы рассматривать, хотя он почти coreutils. Я бы изначально использовал python при возможности, но речь именно о максимальных зависимостях от стандартного окружения. Есть, конечно, вариант на будущее, когда окружение можно будет перенести в WSL, тогда я думаю python будет идеален для решения таких задач.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### дополненная версия ответа

при обработке первой строки можно начинать её с вывода нужных вам символов (чтобы избежать вывода символа новой строки, можно использовать оператор `printf` вместо `print`):

```
{ if (NR==1) {printf "{["}; ... }
```

вывод запятой, разделяющей строки в результирующем файле, можно перенести на начало обработки очередной строки, убрав её из основного вызова `printf`:

```
{ if (NR==1) {printf "{["} else {print ","}; printf ... }
```

ну и в блоке `END{}` можно вывести и завершающие символы:

```
END {print "]}"}
```

#### старый ответ

для того, чтобы добавить первую и последнюю строку в вывод интерпретатора *awk*, в программе можно использовать блоки `BEGIN{}` и `END{}`.

---

пример.

имеется простая программа для *awk*:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb' | awk '{print}'
a
b
```

добавляем в неё блоки, выводящие строку `{[` перед первой строкой вывода и строку `]}` после последней строки вывода:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb' | awk 'BEGIN{print "{["} END{print "]}"} {print}'
{[
a
b
]}
```

---

если добавлять строки нельзя, а надо добавить текст в первую и последнюю строку, то проще ([чем в случае *awk*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12141938/4827341)) будет воспользоваться интерпретатором *sed*:

```
$ echo -e 'a\nb' | sed '1s/^/{[/;$s/$/]}/'
{[a
b]}
```

---

отвечу и на совершенно иной вопрос из комментария:

> Проблема с запятыми в конце, после строчки. Если использовать END, то в итоге будет ,]} awk по шаблону строит и каждую строчку заканчивает запятой, поэтому у меня после END стоит еще один вывод строчки вне шаблона без запятой.

в программе для интерпретатора *awk* довольно громоздко определять последнюю строку. но первую-то определить элементарно (переменная `NR` хранит номер текущей строки входного файла):

```
if (NR!=1) {print ","}
```

Comment: Проблема с запятыми в конце, после строчки. Если использовать END, то в итоге будет ,]} awk по шаблону строит и каждую строчку заканчивает запятой, поэтому у меня после END стоит еще один вывод строчки вне шаблона без запятой.

Comment: ответил на комментарий в конце вопроса, а потом дополнил ответ (в начале).